# SQL Reporting Services Daylight saving time query (pt 2)

Tags: sql

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498815/sql-reporting-services-daylight-saving-time-query) a couple of days ago (SQL Reporting Services Daylight saving time query) which was I received an answer for (thanks very much) but did not elaborate on the whole problem I am experiencing. Not only did I require the returned date time format to account for day light saving but I also need the search parameter @StartDate to allow for DST.

Currently if I key in a scheduled start time of 31/03/2010 11:00 and because the SQL DB has already taken the hours difference into consideration I get no results back. If I key in 31/03/2010 10:00 then the correct details are returned. Is there away using T-SQL or the like to get the search parameter to pass the adjusted time to the DB?

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2008 supports the data type "TIMESTAMP WITH TIMEZONE". Might be worth a try.

You can download a [180-day trial version](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2008/en/us/trial-software.aspx).

In any case, the timezone for an appointment application is what I'd call critical business information. I'd store it in the database, by one of these methods:

1. using the right data type
2. building a user-defined data type
3. adding a column for time zone info